# Grub dual boot without countdown

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

Is it possible to configure grub to have a dual boot setup behaving like described below?

- When turning on PC and doing nothing, the default system should start as soon as possible without waiting for a countdown.
- When wanting to boot another system, a key must be pressed to get to the normal grub menu to select a system.

Furthermore, I recently switched from grub legacy to grub and discovered that it takes notably longer to load before the menu shows up... Is it possible to reduce this time and get a fast boot?

My current `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`: [grub.cfg](http://gist.github.com/3974988)

Comment: Grub2 may be probing more hardware, or your system may be configured with some kind of timeout before the menu shows up. Please post your current `grub.cfg`.

Answer (score 2):

just edit the grub defaults, type

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

and then make sure that `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false` is replaced to `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true`. Also make sure that there is no `#` in front of it. Now close the file and type

```
sudo update-grub
```

which at least on Debian based systems is short for:

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

And you should be done! Now if you want to boot a different operating system, simply hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> while booting.

Comment: What about `GRUB_TIMEOUT` and `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT`?
Note that you may have to use sth. like `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` instead of `update-grub`.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this, you have to change the value of the GRUB_TIMEOUT value from 5 (default) to **0** .

**1** - Setting the timeout to 0 will make GRUB wait nearly 0 sec and boot the default os automatically without counter down.

**2** - if you want to boot another system then **Holding down Shift while booting** get to the normal grub menu to select a system.(if it does not work then set grub_timeout to 1 or 2 sec)

> To change the GRUB_TIMEOUT value:

1. `su` or `sudo` to the root account.

> su -

1. Open the GRUB.cfg file either in `vi` editor or `gedit` (Gedit is easy (GUI))

> vi /boot/grub/grub.cfg

```
 or
```

> gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg

1. Find GRUB_TIMEOUT and change it's value 0
2. Save the changes
3. Update grub

> grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg

If you have any difficulty then watch [my video on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z_luWeHXr60).

Comment: Sorry, read the question again: I mean the main system should start automatically *without doing anything*, not simply leave out the countdown.

Comment: sorry i edit the and now it might help you .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, grub1.9X is much slower than grub0.9X, I want to know how to speed that up as well.

And your first request, you could just reduce the timeout (i.e `set timeout=5`) to 1 second, when you need to boot another system, just kept pressing the arrow keys (up / down / left), grub would stop the counter.